# Download Highchart image in Phonegap application

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

We are developing a mobile application using ***Phonegap + Ionic***. We are using **Highcarts** in our application. We want to give a feature to share the highchart in facebook, Whatsapp or Twitter. Sharing is not a issue with phonegap as there is a plugin available for that.

Issue is that when we want to share any image using the phonegap plugin we need to give a path of the Image and Highchart uses SVG to display the chart.

I have tried converting **SVG into Canvas** and then **exporting** that canvas using **org.devgeeks.Canvas2ImagePlugin** of phonegap but nothing works.

Can somebody please help or share some code if they have achieved something like this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After spending hours we have the solution. Hope this will help others also.

(1) Install Cordova plugin "org.devgeeks.Canvas2ImagePlugin".

(2) Get the SVG html of the highchart.

```
var svg = document.getElementById('chart1').children[0].innerHTML;
```

(3)Create a Canvas html element and append that canvas element inside the div in your page.

```
 var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
 canvas.width = $window.innerWidth;
 canvas.height = 500;

 document.getElementById('divID').innerHTML = '';
 document.getElementById('divID').appendChild(canvas);
```

(4) Canvg will add the Image to the canvas.

```
canvg(canvas, svg, { log: true, ignoreMouse: true, ignoreAnimation: true });
```

(5) With the help of Cordova plugin you can download the image like this

```
window.canvas2ImagePlugin.saveImageDataToLibrary(
    function(path) {
        console.log(path);
    },
    function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    },
    document.getElementById('canvas').getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0]
);
```

Comment: i am getting error  " ERROR: Element 'html' not yet implemented." please let me know how to over come this